# majorVersion and minor in describing dependency package in Vapor

Tags: swift, git, sqlite, server-side, vapor

How to decide what to put for `majorVersion` and `minor` in below code.
I was trying to use sqlite3 with vapor and got stuck here.

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Hello",
    dependencies: [
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", majorVersion: 1, minor: 1)
        ,.Package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/sqlite-driver.git", majorVersion: 1, minor: 0)
        ,.Package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/sqlite-provider.git", majorVersion: 1, minor: 1)
    ],
    exclude: [
        "Config",
        "Database",
        "Localization",
        "Public",
        "Resources",
        "Tests",
    ]
)
```

I am getting error as below when I do `vapor build` -

> Fetching Dependencies [Failed] Check your dependencies' Package.swift
>   files to see where the conflict is. Error: swift-package: error: The
>   dependency graph could not be satisfied. The package
>   (https://github.com/vapor/sqlite-driver.git) with version tag in range
>   (1.1.0..<1.1.9223372036854775807) is not found. Found tags ([0.0.0,
>   0.1.0, 0.1.1, 0.2.0, 0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.3.2, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.7.0, 1.0.0, 1.0.1])

Comment: I am new to Server Side Swift so please clear my doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'dependency graph' error relates to one of your packages depending on a conflicting version of another package. The error messages tells you to 'Check your dependencies' Package.swift files to see where the conflict is.'

You don't need to include both `sqlite-driver` and `sqlite-provider` as the latter already has a built-in dependency on the former. Simply remove the dependency on `sqlite-driver` from your app's `Package.swift`. Also make sure to `vapor clean` afterwards.

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Hello",
    dependencies: [
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", majorVersion: 1, minor: 1),
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/sqlite-provider.git", majorVersion: 1, minor: 1)
    ],
    exclude: [
        "Config",
        "Database",
        "Localization",
        "Public",
        "Resources",
        "Tests",
    ]
)
```

Note: Vapor is now at version 1.2 so you might want to change the version you are pulling in.

Comment: I have another error about CSQLiteMac not building, because there is no file at "/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include/sqlite3.h". Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: I do. Post it as another question and I or someone else will answer it :)